# Element.children not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

I've read all the documentation about `element.children`, (for example [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.children)), and yet I can't get it to work properly on google Chrome. The segment of code I'm working with:

```
<html><head>
    <script src="loadxmldoc.js"></script>
</head>
<body><script>
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");

    document.write("<table border='1'>");
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("day");
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    document.write("<td><table border='1'>");
    document.write("<tr><td>" + x[i].getAttribute("id") + "</td></tr>");

        var y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("time");

        for (var j=0;j<y.length;j++){
            document.write("<tr><td><table border='1'>");
            document.write("<tr><td>Location: " + y[j].getAttribute("id") + ": ");
            document.write("</table></td></tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table></td>");
}
document.write("</table>");
</script></body></html>
```

Problem is, `getElementsByTagName` makes `y.length` 16 every time, instead of 3,3,3,3,1. I did use `childNodes`, but that included text elements. I used `var y=x.item(i).children;` but it does not work on Chrome. It does work on FF, which leads me to believe that either Chrome doesn't support it, or I'm missing something in the head. However, [all documentation I've found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.children) says that this should work with Chrome.

Is this the correct usage of `.children` or is something wrong with Chrome?

Comment: `var y = x[i].getElementsByTagName("time");`, and `document.write` is never ever ever .... ever, the right way to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Like @adeneo said, dont use `document.write`. Do something like, `document.getElementById("container").appendChild(document.createElement("tr"))`

Comment: I was following the code [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp). At any rate, I'm trying to get rid of the former before fixing the later.

Comment: @fat_flying_pigs You should see [this](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Comment: FYI, the reason why `.item` works in FF is that FF returns an `HTMLCollection` while Chrome returns a `NodeList`.

Comment: @Shikiryu Thanks for the link, I had no idea that w3schools was an unreliable source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to thank @Felix Kling for helping me with the answer.

> FYI, the reason why .item works in FF is that FF returns an
>   HTMLCollection while Chrome returns a NodeList. –Felix Kling

`.children` only works with HTMLCollection. NodeList need to be done manually. I picked out the element nodes and threw them into an array.

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("day");
if(isFirefox){   //alternately, you can detect if HTMLCollection
    var y=x.item(i).children;
    document.write(y.length);
}
if(isChrome){    //alternately, you can detect if NodeList
    var y = new Array();
    var currentChild = x.item(i).firstChild;

    while(currentChild!=null){
        if(currentChild.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            y[y.length]=currentChild;
        }
        currentChild=currentChild.nextSibling;
    }
}
for (var j=0;j<y.length;j++){
    /* loop */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On my Chrome version 27 the following works just fine :

```
[].forEach.call (document.body.children, function (e) { console.log (e); });
```

As it does on Firefox 16

Try it on http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/3rBTF/

Answer (score 0):

Try `childNodes`, a standard property. `children` property may not work in all browsers.